# WPF What is the difference between setting the background to transparent and setting opacity on the control?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So I realized that my graph viewer had the axis displaying over the actual items in the graph, so I changed the ZIndex on the grid to display the items over the axis instead.

However, I noticed that I couldn't actually see anything under the actual items because the background of the items were opaque. I think I have two options then, to either set the background of the items to transparent, or to set the opacity of the items. Is there any difference between these two options?

```
              <Grid 
                Grid.Row="0" 
                Grid.RowSpan="2"
                Grid.Column="0" 
                Grid.ZIndex="1"
                >
                <Components:SignalGraphAxis 
                  x:Name="signal_axis"
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  GraphHeight="{Binding Path=GraphHeight}"
                  PenColor="{Binding Path=AxisColor, Mode=OneWay}"
                  PenWidth="{Binding Path=GraphPenWidth, Mode=OneWay}"
                  MinHeight="10"
                  MinWidth="10"
                  AxisTimeScale="{Binding Path=GraphTimeScale}"
                  NumberOfPixelsPerDivision="{Binding Path=NumberOfPixelsPerDivision, Mode=OneWay}"
                  MinDisplayValue ="{Binding Path=MinDisplayValue, Mode=OneWay}"
                  UnitsOfGraphTimePerInch="{Binding Path=UnitsOfTimePerInch, Mode=OneWay}"
                  />
              </Grid>
              <ScrollViewer
                x:Name="signal_scrollviewer"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.RowSpan="2"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                Grid.ZIndex="2"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                CanContentScroll="True"
                Style="{StaticResource SignalScrollViewerStyle}"
                >

                <ItemsPresenter />
              </ScrollViewer>
            </Grid>
```

Comment: Good question. I believe it is the same - as far as the Alpha channel goes. In both cases you'll have a `FF`

Comment: You should stick with the Background where possible. Setting Opacity has some [performance implications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613584(v=vs.110).aspx#Opacity).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Background` property is defined on `Control` class and `Opacity` is defined much higher on `UIElement`.

From MSDN Page [Control.Background Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.background%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> This property only affects a control whose template uses the
>   Background property as a parameter. On other controls, this property
>   has no impact.

Let's try to create a Custom Control to see how this works.

**CustomControl1.cs**

```
public class CustomControl1 : ContentControl
{
    static CustomControl1()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomControl1), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomControl1)));
    }
}
```

**Default Template For CustomControl1**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="My Custom Control " Grid.Row="0" />
                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Please note, the above template doesn't use `Background` property at all in it's `Template`.

Now, Let's try to use that in a Form and see how it behaves:

**Code from Window1.xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <wpfApplication5:CustomControl1 Background="Green">
        <Button Content="Button Within Custom Control" Margin="25"/>
    </wpfApplication5:CustomControl1>
</Grid>
```

The resultant output:

[image]

See, there was no Green background for the rendered CustomControl even though we set the `Background` to `Green` in Window1.xaml.

Now, Lets modify the template to use Background property.

**Template with Background Property**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="My Custom Control " Grid.Row="0" />
                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And the resultant output will now have a the specified background applied.

[image]

I think (couldn't find any references though), Opacity gets applied to the element/Control whether the Control's Template worry about Opacity property or not.

**Window1.xam with Opacity Set on CustomControl**

```
<Grid>
    <wpfApplication5:CustomControl1 Background="Green" Opacity="0.2">
        <Button Content="Button Within Custom Control" Margin="25"/>
    </wpfApplication5:CustomControl1>
</Grid>
```

and resultant Output

[image]

See, the Opacity got applied even though our Custom Control's template doesn't worry anything about `Opacity` property.

Finally, to answer your question: Though either setting `Opacity` to `0` or `Background` to `Transparent` may give you the same visual result. But, for `Background` property, it totally depends on the Control implementation and how it handles Background property. Whereas, with `Opacity` it gets applied from parent elements to down the elements tree to child elements irrespective of the control.

Refer to MSDN Page, [UIElement.Opacity Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.opacity%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to read more on Opacity property and how it behaves when Opacity is set at multiple levels in an element tree.